# Room database is still alive after deleting database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I've deleted the room database but still, I can see the previous rows in my database inspector unless I kill the app manually and reopen it.
The scenario is logging out and reopen the login activity.
The code snippet:

```
class MyAppCompatActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
//...
 private fun logOut() {
        MyAppDatabase.getInstance(context).clearAllTables()
        MyAppDatabase.getInstance(context).close()
        deleteDatabase(MyAppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
        MyFileUtil.deleteDir(cacheDir)
        MyFileUtil.deleteDir(filesDir)
     }
}
```

```
object MyFileUtil{ 
  fun deleteDir(dir: File?): Boolean {
        return if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory) {
            val children = dir.list()
            for (i in children.indices) {
                val success = deleteDir(File(dir, children[i]))
                if (!success) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            dir.delete()
        } else if (dir != null && dir.isFile) {
            dir.delete()
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to clean my database and quickly reopen my activity again by doing an act like kill the app programmatically?

Comment: please share your dao

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are deleting your database file? Those `FileUtil` APIs make me believe you are not deleting the `database` folder where  Android by default puts the databases.

You can get a hold of the directory via [`getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) or better yet, use [`deleteDatabase()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)) to delete them using the same 'name' you pass into Room's builder.

Also, be sure to call [`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase?hl=en#close) on the database before actually deleting it,  otherwise you'll run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks, But the FileUtil is written by me, it is a custom class. And I did `deleteDatabase()` , it didn't work. I've updated my question to be more clear with the 'close()' included code.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `clearAllTables()` from `RoomDatabase`. That way, Room will delete all rows from it's tables created from Entities.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#clearAllTables()

This will not reset the counter for primary keys set to auto-increment.